# Emitter Follower / Common Collector as Negative Feedback Amplifier

Tags: bjt, feedback, emitter-follower, negative-feedback, common-collector

**Background**

From the wikipedia page on Common Collector Amplifiers there is paragraph describing how the circuit acts as a negative feedback amplifier

> The circuit can be explained by viewing the transistor as being under
> the control of negative feedback. From this viewpoint, a common
> collector stage (Fig. 1) is an amplifier with full series negative
> feedback. In this configuration (Fig. 2 with β = 1), the entire output
> voltage VOUT is placed contrary and in series with the input voltage
> VIN. Thus the two voltages are subtracted according to Kirchhoff's
> voltage law (KVL) (the subtractor from the function block diagram is
> implemented just by the input loop) and their extraordinary difference
> Vdiff = VIN - VOUT is applied to the base-emitter junction. The
> transistor continuously monitors Vdiff and adjusts its emitter voltage
> almost equal (less VBEO) to the input voltage by passing the according
> collector current through the emitter resistor RE. As a result, the
> output voltage follows the input voltage variations from VBEO up to
> V+; hence the name, emitter follower.

[image: Common Collector / Emitter Follower Circuit]
[image: Negative Feedback Amplifier]

**Question**

The negative feedback amplifier can be expressed with this equation:

\$Out = (In - Out)*Aol \quad if \quad (\beta = 1)\$

How can the emitter follower be expressed in this way?

**My Thoughts So Far**

\$ In = V_B \quad Out = V_E \$

As mentioned in the wiki article the summation point IN - OUT is applied to Vbe:

\$ V_{BE} = V_B - V_E \$

WRT Aol

\$ V_E = R_E(I_C + I_B) \$

\$ I_C = \beta I_B \$

\$ V_E = R_E(\beta I_B + I_B) \$

\$ V_E = R_EI_B(\beta + 1) \$

At this point I have an equation relating output to base current (proportional to input voltage) multiplied by a gain but I cant see the step to get from this to the negative feedback amplifier equation

**Note**

This isnt a question about how the feedback mechanism works. I understand the gain of the transistor causes base current to be multiplied increasing output voltage across \$R_E\$ which in turn decreases base current. This question is only about modelling the circuit as a negative feedback amplifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Vin=Vb**, **Aol=gmRE**  (gm: transconductance) and **beta=1** your block diagram results in the classical common collector transfer function (output VE)

**Acl=VE/Vin=gmRE/(1+gmRE)**.
The loop gain is **Aloop=gmRE**

Comment: Please can you expand on how you found gmRE to be the open loop gain

Comment: I understand now, \$ I_C = g_m V_{BE} \$ then using the approximation \$ I_E \sim I_C \$ output voltage is given by \$ V_E = I_E * R_E = g_m V_{BE} R_E \$ if we expand \$ V_{BE} \$ we get the negative feedback amplifier equation \$ V_E = (V_B - V_E) g_m R_E \$

Comment: Yes - OK. At the input summing junction we have, of course, VBE=VB-VE.. Evaluating the gain of the block diagram, we see that the result meets the classical well-known gain expression. Hence, the block diagram mirrors the reality and we can derive Aol and the loop gain expression from it.